# Issue with finding element with selenium driver and Instagram login

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Iam trying to make a program to scrape all my followers then basically be able to store it into a dictionary with the key as my followers names and the value as there total followers, then sort this dictionary to find my top 5 or 10 most followed followers. However when I try to login to Instagram I am getting this error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49683/devtools/browser/0e7b8ef3-8f6b-48fd-87a6-ce61c11decf6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mathe\OneDrive\Documents\Data analysis\Python\InstagramAnalyzer\main.py", line 93, in <module>
    login(driver)
  File "c:\Users\mathe\OneDrive\Documents\Data analysis\Python\InstagramAnalyzer\main.py", line 22, in login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div/input[@name='username']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

MY CURRENT CODE (pass and username has been moved out, but this isn't the issue as I have confirmed it was the right password and username)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# The account you want to check
account = "xxx"

def login(driver):
    username = "xxx"   # Your username
    password = "XXX"   # Your password

    # Load page
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
    
    # Login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='password']").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/button").click()
    
    key = input("Enter activation code:")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='key']").send_keys(key)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/button").click()

    # Wait for the login page to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "See All")))


def scrape_followers(driver, account):
    # Load account page
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/{0}/".format(account))

    # Click the 'Follower(s)' link
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("follower").click()

    # Wait for the followers modal to load
    xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))

    SCROLL_PAUSE = 0.5  # Pause to allow loading of content
    driver.execute_script("followersbox = document.getElementsByClassName('_gs38e')[0];")
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return followersbox.scrollHeight;")

    # We need to scroll the followers modal to ensure that all followers are loaded
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("followersbox.scrollTo(0, followersbox.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait for page to load
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE)

        # Calculate new scrollHeight and compare with the previous
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return followersbox.scrollHeight;")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    # Finally, scrape the followers
    xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li"
    followers_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

    followers_temp = [e.text for e in followers_elems]  # List of followers (username, full name, follow text)
    followers = []  # List of followers (usernames only)

    # Go through each entry in the list, append the username to the followers list
    for i in followers_temp:
        username, sep, name = i.partition('\n')
        followers.append(username)

    print("===================================")
    print("FOLLOWERS")

    return followers


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/mathe/OneDrive/Documents/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    
    # driver = wd.Chrome(driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
    
    try:
        login(driver)
        followers = scrape_followers(driver, account)
        print(followers)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'your chrome driver path') 

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
time.sleep(3)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
username = input("Enter Username")
element.send_keys(username)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
password = input("Enter Password")
element.send_keys(password)

element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**Hope this helps !!**

Comment: I swapped my code in my login function to what you provided but I still get this error : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='username']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Comment: Did you give your chrome driver path correctly?? Or using any other browser??

Comment: yes mine is like this driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/mathe/OneDrive/Documents/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

Comment: This code works perfectly for me ...If not , try with full xpath . Copy the full xpath of the element and try with that.

Comment: Are you able to try the rest of my code with your code, see if the rest works?

Comment: You need in headless mode?

Comment: ok so i removed my options in the webdriver and it seems to work now, do you know how I would overcome the activation code thing Instagram has after you login

Comment: Activation code??? I haven't come across that thing?? || If the above code helps you please upvote my answer :)

Comment: Yes i will thanks! the acivation code is after you login there is another input field which asks you to enter a code which is sent to your phone

Comment: I guess i can do the exact same as username and pass word? but I am struggling to know how to find what css selector to use like how does the @name= etc work so I can change it for the security code

Comment: Oh i haven't come across that because i haven't added mobile number. I don't think theres a way to bypass that other than removing mobile number from Instagram. If theres a solution , it should interact with your smses and should return the OTP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236392/discussion-between-httpanand-and-ericbailey101).

Answer (score 0):

See you are using this line :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
```

which is incorrect, since the locator is not correct.

try with this locator instead :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
def login(driver):
  username = "xxx"  # Your username
  password = "XXX"  # Your password

  # Load page
  driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
  wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys(username)
  wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys(password)
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

Comment: I swapped the line of code but still gives this issue : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='username']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Comment: okay in headless mode we need explicit wait, try the updated 1 code above

Comment: Can you show me the full code you have in my login function, as I don't want to type anything wrong in and get different output to you thanks

Comment: Check out the updated 1 code above. should help you past the login.

Comment: have you also put : # Wait for the login page to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "See All"))) Line of code in login function at the end, cause now I get selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: No, that is not part of the original error stack trace. Did you run what I have provided above ?